# Diagram for wiring switches and a light

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a switch that controls the room light and all the outlets.

I would like to make the outlets always hot.

The source of the power is behind the switch and there are 3 outlets in the room.

How would I make the outlets always hot and only control the ceiling light?

**Edit:** Here are the pictures. 1st picture is the diagram of what is currently happening behind the walls, 2nd, and 3rd pictures are left and right view of the Switch. 4th and 5th pictures are right and left view of Outlet 1.

There are a total of 5 Outlets and 1 Ceiling light. These are all attached behind Outlet 1 and controlled by 1 Switch. I don't know how the white wires are attached behind Outlet 1 since these are not attached behind Outlet 1. I think these might be behind Outlet 5.

Outlet 5 is in the other room wall which is located directly on the opposite side of Outlet 1. Green colors are caps. The red wire is capped behind the Switch and it's linked to the red wire coming from the ceiling light behind Outlet 1 but it's not being used.

Outlet 1 picture below, Botton right black wire is attached with the rest of the black wires, I removed it for the sake of the picture.

Also, behind Outlet 1, there are 3 white wires attached, One on top left, the second botton left and the third is part of the outlet and it's going somewhere. I think all these white wires in the box of Outlet 5.

I just don't know how these white wires are attached together. I would like the light switch to only control the ceiling light. I do have some spare 14/3 romax if needed.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: We need to see clear photos of the inside of the switch box, detailed descriptions of the wires power in, power to outlets etc. Are you sure the power comes into the switch box first?  As much info as you can supply in order to get an informed answer.

Comment: Can you post clear photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Comment: Are both plugins in an outlet controlled by the switch?  It's common to have one of them controlled by the switch and the other always hot. If so, it's easy, if not you're going to have to do some more wiring.

Comment: Thank you. I added pictures with details and a diagram.

Comment: Are "Outlet 1" and "Outlet 5" in the same junction box?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if there is a junction box to be honest. They did terrible work around the house.

Answer (score 3):

Connect the light to thge red wire instead of the black
use the cap from the red to cap the black.

At the switch connect the red in place of the switched black.

Connect the old switched black to the black source and use a short piece of black wire to connect these two to where the source connected to the switch.

[image: changes highlighted]

Comment: Thank you Jasen! This makes sense! Really appreciate your help. Now I don't need to touch anything else!